# Unable to remove a port from default VLAN

Tags: cisco, port, switch, vlan

I am unable to remove a port from my **default VLAN**.

I've tried:

```
Switch(config)#interface FastEthernet 0/1
Switch(config-if)#no switchport access vlan 1
```

It has no errors but when I check it using:

```
#show vlan brief
```

Then the port I try to remove is still in vlan 1.

I'm using a **Cisco Catalyst 3550**.

- Is it possible to remove a port from this VLAN?

Comment: AFAIK, It cannot not be a member of any VLAN. If you don't want the port in VLAN 1 then you need to assign it to another VLAN. A port cannot be removed from the Native/Default VLAN without being assigned to another VLAN.

Comment: Like Joe says...if you don't want it in any vlan then just disable the port, it'll still be a member of VLAN 1 but won't pass traffic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A port must have a VLAN assignment. If you need it to be completely disconnected, set it to a nonexistent VLAN and shut down the port.

```
interface fa0/1
switchport access vlan 901
no switchport access vlan 1
shutdown
```

(I'm not sure if the "no" is required. Don't have a switch at my fingers with an open port to test).

That said, `shutdown` should be sufficient in and of itself.

Comment: Depending on the switch you could set the interface to `no switchport`, but you would need to remember to set it back when configuring as a L2 interface.  Also the `no switchport access vlan 1` is not required, as you have set it do a different vlan already.